# Rails app in docker container doesn't reload in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I followed this [docker-compose tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) on howto start a rails app.
It runs perfectly but the app isn't reloaded when I change a controller.

What can it be missing?

Comment: There's a number of things that can get in between file system events and your container. Could you add a link to the tutorial or some more info about what you have setup so far.

Comment: here is the tutorial https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/, to be more precise I use docker for mac

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 42):

I was struggling with this as well, there are 2 things that you need to do:

1. Map the current directory to the place where Docker is currently hosting the files.
2. Change the config.file_watcher to ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker

## Step 1:

In your Dockerfile, check where are you copying/adding the files.

See my Dockerfile:

```
# https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project

FROM ruby:2.5.0
# The qq is for silent output in the console
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs vim

# Sets the path where the app is going to be installed
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/

# Creates the directory and all the parents (if they don't exist)
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

# This is given by the Ruby Image.
# This will be the de-facto directory that 
# all the contents are going to be stored. 
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# We are copying the Gemfile first, so we can install 
# all the dependencies without any issues
# Rails will be installed once you load it from the Gemfile
# This will also ensure that gems are cached and onlu updated when 
# they change.
COPY Gemfile ./
COPY Gemfile.lock ./
# Installs the Gem File.
RUN bundle install

# We copy all the files from the current directory to our
# /app directory
# Pay close attention to the dot (.)
# The first one will select ALL The files of the current directory, 
# The second dot will copy it to the WORKDIR!
COPY . .
```

The `/var/www` directory is key here. That's the inner folder structure of the image, and where you need to map the current directory to.

Then, in your docker-compose, define an index called volumes, and place that route there (Works for V2 as well!):

```
version: '3'
services:
  rails:
    # Relative path to Dockerfile. 
    # Docker will read the Dockerfile automatically
    build: .
    # This is the one that makes the magic
    volumes:
    - "./:/var/www"
```

[image: Directory of the current project]

The image above is for reference. Check that the docker-compose and Dockefile are in the same directory. They **not** necessarily need to be like this, you just have to be sure that the directories are specified correctly.

docker-compose works **relative to the file**. The `./`means that it will take the current docker-compose directory (In this case the entire ruby app) as the place where it's going to host the image's content.

The `:`  just a way to divide between the where it's going to be vs where the image has it.

The next part: `/var/www/` is the same path you specified in the Dockerfile.

## Step 2:

Open development.rb (Can be found in /config/environments)

and look for `config.file_watcher`, replace:

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
```

for:

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

This would do a polling mechanism instead.

If that doesn't work, try adding the following line in the environment file, in this case development.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

That's it!

Remember, that anything that is not routes.rb, and it's not inside the app folder, it's highly probable that the Rails app is going to need to be reloaded manually.

Comment: I already had Step 1 covered, Step 2 fixed this issue for me. This should be the answer.

Comment: works great, thank you. Just to add: it does not have to be `/var/www`, it could be any directory you want eg `/my-app-name` then you have to be consistent with it across all instances of the `/var/www`.

Answer (score 2):

Incrementing @Jose A's answer, I changed the property `config.cache_classes` inside development.rb to `false` and it solved the problem. Following, its explanation:

```
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, saved me.
Edited the answer above with your input :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild the image with the next command to add the changes to the dockerized app:

```
docker-compose build
```

And after it you need to restart the app with `docker-compose up` to recreate the docker container for your app.

Comment: some answer told me 'added volumes'. but i have already volume in docker-compose.Thanks to your answer, i have solved

Answer (score 1):

You should create a volume that maps your local/host source code with the same code located inside docker in order to work on the code and enable such features.

Here's an example of a (docker-compose) mapped file that I'm updating in my editor without having to go through the build process just to see my updates:

```
  volumes:
    - ./lib/radius_auth.py:/etc/freeradius/radius_auth.py
```

Without mapping host <--> guest, the guest will simply run whatever code it has received during the build process.

Comment: yes, and in Rails you need to add: `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker` to your environment/development.rb

Answer (score 0):

i got same issue, for someone, i dont know your issue is same mine, but i hope you can fix, for me i could fix when i did that.

```
1, Restart mac
2, Delete application.yml
3, make
4, make up
```

Comment: or "docker-sync" Please try stop stop once. If you change the branch, it will not be synchronized a lot.